# Set Jenkins build cause manually via REST API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

I'm looking to update the default build cause when invoking a build via the REST API. I see that this is possible by appending the `cause` parameter when using the `Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)` option, but what about when I make a `/build` POST request using the normal `user:apiToken` format?

Essentially I'm looking to replace `Started by user xxxx` with a custom string. I'll also accept plugin recommendations as a fallback if this isn't possible by default.